# SQL how to count but only count one instance if two columns match?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

Wondering how to select from a table:

```
FIELDID personID  purchaseID   dateofPurchase
--------------------------------------------------
2         13       147         2014-03-21 00:00:00
3         15       165         2015-03-23 00:00:00
4         13       456         2018-03-24 00:00:00
5         1       133         2018-03-21 00:00:00
6         23       123         2013-03-22 00:00:00
7         25       456         2013-03-21 00:00:00
8         25       456         2013-03-23 00:00:00
9         22       456         2013-03-28 00:00:00
10        25       589         2013-03-21 00:00:00
11        82       147         1991-10-22 00:00:00
12        82       453         2003-03-22 00:00:00
```

I'd like to get a result table of two columns: weekday and the number of purchases of each weekday, but only count the distinct days of purchases if done by the same person on the same day - for example since personID 25 purchased two things on 2013-03-21, that should only count as one 'thursday' instead of 2.

Basically, if the personID and the dateofPurchase are the same for more than one row, only count it once is what I want.

Here is what I have currently: It does everything correctly except it will count the above scenario under the thursday twice, when I would only want to add one:

```
SELECT v.wkday as day, COUNT(*) as 'absences'
FROM dbo.AttendanceRecord pr CROSS APPLY
     (VALUES (CASE WHEN DATEPART(WEEKDAY, date) IN (1, 7)
                   THEN 'Weekend'
                   ELSE DATENAME(WEEKDAY, date)
              END)
     ) v(wkday)
GROUP BY v.wkday;
```

to clarify:

If an item is purchased for at least one puchaseID on a specific day they will be counted as purchased for that day, and do not need to be counted again for each new purchase ID on that day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want to count distinct persons, so that would be:

```
COUNT(DISTINCT personid) as absences
```

Note that single quotes are not appropriate around column aliases.  If you need to escape them, use square braces.

EDIT:

If you want to count distinct person-days, then you can use:

```
COUNT(DISTINCT CONCAT(personid, ':', dateofpurchase) as absences
```

Comment: Not sure if this is what I want, since it returns Thursday/Friday/and Weekend as having 2 each, when I know the correct answer would be Thursday - 3, Friday - 2, Weekend - 3